# MySQLdb Error in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache

I am totally lost and not able to find the solution for my problem. I started virtualenv and installed latest version of django in it with python version `2.7`. Then i followed django tutorial but instead of working on development server, i used apache2 localhost and everything was working fine. Then to check for mysql support, i changed the settings file and installed `mysqlclient` and used `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate` and nothing went wrong. Finally i restarted apache and there appeared `500 Internal Server Error`. I am now providing apache error log and my settings file.

```
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190280 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190504 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunner/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190516 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190711 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190724 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     django.setup()
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190925 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.190938 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.191272 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.191288 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     app_config.import_models(all_models)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.191620 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.191641 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.191934 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.191949 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192004 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192043 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192083 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192123 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192162 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192201 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192241 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192456 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/runner/models.py", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.192469 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     class Question(models.Model):
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.193404 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.193436 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.193520 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.193532 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194132 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194165 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194409 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194424 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194730 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194745 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194807 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194818 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194876 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194887 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194927 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.194966 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195005 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195045 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195084 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195123 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195163 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195234 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]   File "/home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195245 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140]     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
[Thu Feb 04 11:24:13.195297 2016] [:error] [pid 23833] [remote 127.0.0.1:25140] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: /home/kapil/work/database/roadrunner/roadrunnerground/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

Here is the settings.py content regarding database configuration.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'roadrunner',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'kapilgarg',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

From the last line of apache error log, where it is pointed `_mysql.so : undefined symbol`, it seems that there is some linking problem or some version mismatching problem. Can someone please please help me ?? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your apache config. Which operating system are you using, and which packages have you installed? You say you are using Python 2.7, but the traceback mentions Python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Install the module in your virtual environment

```
pip install MySQL-python
```